# Null Vector in LabVIEW

Tags: matlab, null, labview

I need to find the "null vector" of the matrix in LabVIEW. But I couldn't find the related block. 
 For example in MatLab, for the Matrix A we can simply find the null vector with the command: null(A); But in LabVIEW I can't do this till now. 
 Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way to do this is to use the MathScript node, which allows for many Matlab commands to be used in LabVIEW.  Here's an example:

[image: null(A)]

If you don't want to use the MathScript node, then you can get the result from the "Matrix V" output of "SVD decomposition" as shown in the second part of the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your Tip. 
I have used this but I looking for the way which doesn't need to use MathScript code. 
I'm working on the Real-Time project and it's very important for me to avoid using Matlab. Because it is very slower than LabVIEW in this usage.

Comment: If you don't want to use MathScript, use code shown at the bottom of the image, with VIs "SVD Decomposition" and "Matrix Rank", neither of which use MathScript.